# Expand application bar in Windows Phone 8 app from code

Tags: windows-phone-8, expand, application-bar

I wonder if there is any way of expanding windows phone 8 application bar from code.
I know that this was not possible on windows phone 7 but maybe they done something in the SDK so its possible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar property. In particular, Buttons and MenuItems.

Comment: Should i guess here what you really mean?

Comment: Oh, I see what you are asking. No, that's not currently possible in WP8.

Comment: Ok thanks. We sure hope they will make it possible in next SDK.